# Django select_related() but only some fields

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-queryset

I would like to use select_related() but without loading all the fields of the model loaded via select_related.

I'd just like to filter the model fields loaded via select_related without affecting the other queryset fields.
There is the solution to use only() and explicitly specify all fields but this is not practical when you have a lot of fields.

The solution of using exclude() and excluding only fields is not practical either in case of evolution. (Adding fields to the model)

Is there another way?

With an example, it will be more understandable:

```
class User(model.Model):
    username = models.Charfield(max_length=50)
    # ... many fields here

class Musician(models.Model):
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    instrument = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    # ...
    # many of fields here
```

I would like to select all fields of the "Musician" model and only username of User by performing a single SQL query using Django ORM.

Comment: With `.defer(..)` or `.only(..)`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem It is not practical... I'd like to do something like this: `defer('created_by*').only('*', 'created_by__username)`